# How to use a dynamic value for cache key with ActiveModel::Serializers (v0.10.0.rc1)

Tags: caching, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I am using a database-driven solution for labels and translations that I would like to cache at the serializer level. Here is my serializer.

```
class AppLabelSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  cache key: 'app_label', expires_in: 3.hours
  attributes :id, :key, :label, :label_plural

  def key
    object.app_label_dictionary.key
  end
end
```

The problem is that I need to cache the labels for each language, so I need to specify the language somewhere in the key. I tried this solution:

`cache key: "#{scope.app_language.name}/app_label", expires_in: 3.hours`

But the value of `scope` isn't available there for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted [an issue on the AMS github page](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/943) and went back and forth with @joaomdmoura and @groyoh until we came up with this *temporary* solution. It works on my end and it'll do for now until AMS makes an official decision on the best solution.

```
module ActiveModel
  class Serializer
    class Adapter
      def cache_key
        key = @klass._cache_key
        key = @cached_serializer.instance_exec &key if key.is_a?(Proc)
        key ? "#{key}/#{@cached_serializer.object.id}-#{@cached_serializer.object.updated_at}" : @cached_serializer.object.cache_key
      end
    end
  end
end

class AppLabelSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  cache key: ->(){ "#{scope.app_language.name}/app_labels" }, expires_in: 3.hours
  attributes :id, :label, :label_plural    
end
```

It looks funny, but yes you just paste in that extension of the ActiveModel module right into your already existing serializer file.

**NOTE: This only works with v0.10.0.rc1**

Comment: Why do you have both an instance method for the key and a proc? Are both approaches supported by the monkeyhack, or do you need to use both?

Comment: You don't need both. The `key` method I was defining was just the key field on an AppLabel, and I needed to redefine it. I have removed it from the example because it was unnecessary and confusing. Does that answer your question?